# Wordpress Shortcode that query some value from MySql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, shortcode

I've a MySql table where I put some value: id, name of opportunity, category of opportunity, commission etc etc. Now I need to create (automatically) a shortcode that call these value win an array, so for example if i write `[opportunity id="1"]` wordpress display banner of the opportunity in the database that have `id=1`.

This is my code

```
function opportunity_banner_shortcode($atts) { 
    extract(shortcode_atts(array("id" => ''), $atts));

  global $table_prefix, $wpdb, $user_level;
  $table_name = $table_prefix . "opportunities";

  $finds = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$table_name}", ARRAY_A);
  if(sizeof($finds)){
    foreach($finds as $find) 
        return "<a href='" . $find["opp_link"]. 
               "'><img src='" . $find["opp_banner_preview"]."'></a> ";
    } 
}
add_shortcode('opportunity', 'opportunity_banner_shortcode');
```

Thanks to all

Comment: What **is** the trouble?  Please state the error/issue clearly in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the query should be

```
$finds = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE id={$id}",
   ARRAY_A);
```

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad I could help. Do me a favor and vote for my answer, or choose it, by clicking on the big check mark or the triangle over the 0. Thanks. :)